# Static Assert for Public Inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, static-assert

I built a helper class that would construct a custom class via templates, this custom class must inherit from a certain class, I can check for this with `std::is_base_of`.

However I also need to check that the inheritance is public, how can this be achieved?

For reference, here is a stripped down version of the class, I have the `std::is_base_of` in there.

```
template<class CustomSink>
class Sink
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<BaseSink, CustomSink>::value, "CustomSink must derive from BaseSink");
    //Some static assert here to check if custom sink has publicly inherited BaseSink 
    //static_assert(is_public.....
public:
    template<class... Args>
    Sink(Args&&... args)
    {
    }
    ~Sink()
    {
    }       
};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to both [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233393/quentin) and [cpplearner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4672588/cpplearner) for pointing me in the right direction. I found [Quentins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233393/quentin) answer worked fine if the assert should pass, but on a failed case the static_assert would not catch the error, instead it would be generated inside the template, removing the benefit of the clear `static_assert` message.

Then [cpplearner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4672588/cpplearner) mentioned `std::is_convertible` which I had tried to use before but had forgotten about needing the `*`, also the B and D seemed to be the wrong way round.

All of this lead me to creating:

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible<Derived*, Base*>::value, "Derived must inherit Base as public");
```

Which seems to do the job, below is the full code as a complete example.

```
#include <type_traits>

class Base { };
class Derived : Base { };
class DerivedWithPublic : public Base { };

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<DerivedWithPublic*, Base*>::value, "Class must inherit Base as public");
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<Derived*, Base*>::value, "Derived must inherit Base as public");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, public inheritance is the only case where an implicit pointer conversion can be performed (a reference conversion could be achieved via an overloaded operator).

```
template <class T>
std::true_type is_public_base_of_impl(T*);

template <class T>
std::false_type is_public_base_of_impl(...);

template <class B, class D>
using is_public_base_of = decltype(is_public_base_of_impl<B>(std::declval<D*>()));
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa7f443d778d31f8)

Comment: Or just use `std::is_convertible<B*, D*>`?